# How to calculate standard deviaton from sql query in python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am a total beginner so I am hoping for some help. Sorry if there is an answer already, but i can't find it.

I am querying data with python from column in SQL Server. It looks something like this.

```
 import pypyodbc
 connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};',.....
 c = connection.cursor()
 command = (" SELECT VALUE FROM testserver2")
 c.execute(command)
 for row in c.fetchall():
 print(row)
```

Result:

[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d2op.jpg) and it goes on in a similar manner.

I want to calculate standard deviaton using values in this column(shown in query result). First i want to calculate SD with first 5 values, then values from 2 row to 6 row, 3 row to 7 row, 4 row to 8 row and so on till the end.

I will use pstdev function from statistics to calculate standard deviaton, but i don't know how to take 5 values at the time as described above. I was trying some stuff with slicer and chunker and some other stuff i could find on the web, but didn't manage to produce something useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use a list comprehension, slice the list, calculate asynchronously. There are many ways of accomplishing what you want.